# what does "it raised in its wake other, more troubling questions" mean?

Tags: meaning

“But this was not a question which could be disposed of so easily; it raised in its wake other, more troubling questions. ”

I find the structure of the sentence above hard to understand. I even doubt if it is correct grammarly. Should it be "it raised in the wake of other, more troubling questions"?

Comment: The question is being likened to a ship, which creates a *wake* of disturbed water behind it as it moves.

Comment: [correction: I doubt whether it's correct grammar OR grammar-wise. The word you used doesn't exist in English. It's an online, brand-name program for correcting English.]

Comment: The phrase can be reordered as "it raised other more troubling questions in its wake".

Comment: Possibly the easiest punctuation error to make is forgetting the second comma in a phrase that is set of by commas. The sentence ought to read as follows: "But this was not a question which could be disposed of so easily; it raised in its wake other, more troubling, questions." The phrase "more troubling" is set off by commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But this was not a question which could be disposed of so easily; it raised in its wake other, more troubling questions.

The phrase [in the wake of](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-the-wake-of) means

> 1. following directly or close behind
> 2. following as a consequence

The clause

> *it* raised in *its* wake other, more troubling questions [emphasis added]

means that that *question* raised other, more troubling ones following the attempted disposal of the original *question*.

Your rewording does not make sense:

> it raised [in the wake of other, more troubling questions] [what]?

What did it raise?

**Edit**

Note the pronoun *its* is used and refers to the subject of the clause *it* (The *question*).

**Edit After Further Queries From The OP**

The structure is

> *it* raised [in *its* wake] [other, more troubling questions]

We build up leaving out the preposition phrase and some other words first:

> it raised [questions]

> it raised [other, more troubling questions]

When did it raise them?

> it raised [after the event] [other, more troubling questions]

> *it* raised [following directly behind the attempted disposal of the *question*] [other, more troubling questions]

Comment: Yes, it's important to point out that here, the pronoun its is used.

Comment: I still don't understand the structure of "its wake other, more troubling questions". It looks like that two nouns are put together.

Comment: The main idea is "it [the question] raised other, more troubling questions"; the idiomatic clause "in its [the question's] wake" elaborates on the way those other questions were raised.

Comment: @Qiang Lu, I have elaborated my answer.